# How to keep methods collapsed in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a project which contains 15 classes. If I collapse the methods and restart Android Studio, everything works fine but if I sync the `build.gradle` file and restart Android Studio again, the methods from some classes are not collapsed anymore. This is happening not in all classes in my project just in those that are not opened. So, let's say I'm working on 5 classes and 10 are closed, it I sync the `build.gradle` file, the 5 opened classes are ok but the rest of 10 are not.

How to always keep methods collapsed in Android Studio, even if I sync the `build.gradle` file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the configuration of Android Studio for this. Check below:

**Environment:**

```
Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 5, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.13.4
```

Go to **Preferences > Editor > General > Code Folding** and check all the check boxes you want and click apply:

[image]

I hope it will work.

Comment: @IoanaP. My pleasure. Please upvote as well. Thank you!